# jQuery load() from within ajaxComplete() callback causing multiple loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, methods

I've been staring at this one for a while and I'm completely stumped. You'll need firebug for this, take a look at the AJAX requests. They seem to be multiplying after each click of next and previous until it's too slow to load entirely:

http://www.ftsdev.com/freegreen/virtual-tour-prototype/virtual-tour.html

All the JavaScript source for this is in:

```
/freegreen/virtual-tour-prototype/js/virtual-tour.js
```

Functions to look at:

```
launchVirtualTour()
$('#vt-next').one('click',function()
$('#vt-prev').one('click',function()
```

When `ajaxComplete()` is called I check the file that loaded against an `Array` outside of the callback function. This allows me to determine whether or not it's the first or last element in the series so that I can hide the `Previous` or `Next` buttons accordingly. I have a feeling that the problems lies somewhere in lines 80-82 where I add `1` to the `inArray()` value stored in `indexInArray`.

I've searched around but can't find any similar situations out there, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I briefly tried out the page. From a quick skim of the code and my gut reaction, it looks like you aren't unbinding previously bound click events. As far as I can tell this is the flow to your bug:

1. User clicks to bring up a slide show
2. You bind next/prev click events
3. User clicks around, using the next/prev buttons
4. User clicks out of the current slide show
5. User clicks into another slide show
6. You bind next/prev click events
7. User clicks around, using the next/prev buttons, causing content to be called twice

You need to unbind the click events when the user clicks out of the first slide show. Or don't bind in step 6.

Comment: Thanks so much Sam, I'll try debugging based on the above first thing tomorrow morning and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hah, I just took a shot at it and it worked. I move the events outside of the ajaxComplete and made them live events so that they would attach to the contents of the AJAX loaded content and it worked.

Thanks so much for this Sam, I never thought I could resolve this one so quick!

Comment: Very glad to hear Kevin. :-) Good luck with the rest!